# Is the dimension of a smooth manifold an invariant of the underlying set in it?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $S$ a set and $f:M\to S$ a bijection (assuming of course, that such a function does exist).

It's an easy exercise to show that $S$ can be given a differentiable structure such that $f$ is a diffeomorphism. It's almost as easy to show that such an structure is unique (by the maximality of an atlas). Given a chart, say $$x:U\subset M\to R^n,$$ of the manifold $M$, $n$ the dimension of $M$, just set $$x^f=x\circ f^{-1}:f(U)\subset S\to R^n$$ as a chart on $S$. It's seen that a change of coordinates on $S$ is nothing but a change of coodinates on $M$.

Now, my question: there exists a bijection $$f:(0,1)\times (0,1)\to (0,1),$$ from the unit square (as an open submanifold of $R^2$) to the open interval $(0,1)$ of the real line $R$. It's a fact. By the above just considered, the set $(0,1)$ can be given a differentiable structure such that it's diffeomorphic to $(0,1)\times (0,1)$, a manifold of dimension 2, right? Even $(0,1)\times (0,1)$ can be viewed as a 1-dimensional smooth manifold by considering $f^{-1}$ instead of $f$, isn't it?

I must be misunderstanding something here, because in either cases I just can't realize the open sets on the respective ranges (of $f$ and $f^{-1}$).

What can you say about this?

Comment: Every positive-dimensional manifold has cardinality $\mathbb R$. They are all in bijection.

Comment: Interesting... How is the prove (references)?

Comment: I wrote out all the details [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031121/build-a-topological-manifold-starting-from-a-set/1031967#1031967).

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. Miller.

Comment: Maybe one source of confusion is that when you consider the usual manifold structures on $(0,1)$ and $(0,1)^2$, then even though there exists a bijection between them, it cannot be a diffeomorphism. In fact the inverse isn't even continuous if the original bijection is. So whatever "structure" you are transferring to $(0,1)^2$ using your proposal, it definitely looks nothing like the usual manifold structure.

Comment: (Side note: there can't be a continuous bijection $(0,1)^2 \to (0,1)$ at all. This would imply that $(0,1/2) \cup (1/2, 1)$ is path-connected.)